# Encode column values from lond to base 36

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, encode

I have a file with columns like these (tab separated)

```
hit_stamp       x_id     column_to_encode       type  count
2016-02-19 11:00:39     3479    1727468938147435143     display 1
2016-02-19 11:00:43     3479    8993948836180821483     display 1
2016-02-19 11:00:45     3479    5429425032128142743     display 1
2016-02-19 11:00:46     3479    1221384347847832843     display 1
2016-02-19 11:00:46     3479    2242413443751657343     display 1
2016-02-19 11:00:46     3479    4803565579589481863     display 1
:
:
```

Is it possible to encode the long values in "column_to_encode" to base 36 using bash or some linux command?

I don't mind doing this when I pull data from the the database too.
Here is the query I use:

```
select hit_stamp, x_id, column_to_encode, type,  count(1) count from xyzTable group by hit_stamp, x_id, column_to_encode, type;
```

Is there a way where I can cast the column_to_encode to base 36 in the query itself?

Answer (score 3):

The mysql [conv function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_conv) is used to convert bases.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no build-in conversion you can use the handy basic calculator `bc` for the base conversion as well, i.e.

```
$ bc <<< "obase=36; 370"
10 10
```

probably better to create a function

```
$ b36() { echo $(bc <<< "obase=36; $1"); }
```

and for converting to the right alphabet an array lookup

```
$ BASE36=($(echo {0..9} {A..Z}))
$ echo ${BASE36[@]}
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
```

now, what's left is looping through the digits

```
$ for i in $(b36 1727468938147435143); do echo -n ${BASE36[$i]}; done; echo
D4HCMQKMQEMF
```

Comment: For readers, bc doesn't stand for base conversion, it's basic calculator.  od is the more direct tool meant for base conversions